# Log requests with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

How I can log requests to Spring REST service via Spring Security ?
(Point me on some examples)

Comment: Amibiguous..you want to log THAT the service is accessed or WHO accesses your service?

Comment: I want to log who access service

Answer (score 0):

Once Spring Security is properly set up and working, you can access the credentials (or at least, the username) of the currently logged-in user by getting the SecurityContext, and from there the UserDetails:

```
final Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

String username = null;

if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
    username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
} else {
    username = principal.toString();
}

log.debug("User: " + username + " has accessed the service");
```

We did that in one of our applications. It was a Spring MVC program, but that should not matter much.

However I would not really log the username into a file somewhere. You might try and set up some kind of protocol-database, and log more information ("X accessed MYSERVICE at YY time doing Z" or something)

Answer (score 0):

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>//</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring-config.xml

```
...

<bean class="com.examlple.MyLogFilter" id="logFilter"/>

...

<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy" id="securityFilter">
    <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
          <sec:filter-chain filters="logFilter,otherfilter1,otherfilter2" pattern="/myRESTservicePath/**"/>

....
```

`MyLogFilter` is a simple servlet Filter implementation